# AngularJS: Memory Leak with ng-repeat using custom objects (w/simple PLUNKR)

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, angularjs-ng-repeat

(simple plunkr demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Adh2P65ZS8YHYJZhLMk))

### **SUMMARY:**

There is a leak using ng-repeat *after the 2nd wave* iterating over an 'array' of custom objects like this :

```
    <div ng-repeat="d_sampleObject in mySampleObjects">
        {{d_sampleObject.description}}
    </div>
```

Memory profile reveals an extra 'd_sampleObject' left over and not de-referenced. More details (via a controller and an injected service) below.  A simple demonstration also in the provided plunkr link.  Any thoughts and help greatly appreciated in advance!

**NOTE:** 'mySampleObjects' is an array of the following instances:

```
        ml.MySampleObject = function (id) {

            this.id = id;
            this.description = 'this is object #:' + ' '+id;
        }
```

### **DETAILS:**

I have a custom object model that reflects the business domain objects that we utilize in our AngularJS app.  I have found that when I pass an instance of one of my custom objects to ng-repeat, a reference is kept to it (I think by Angular) and memory is not freed. This happens on the second 'wave' (click on 'refresh') of the ng-repeat as it iterates, again, over its array of objects. This leak is exposed in my Profile tests (in Chrome) .  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Adh2P65ZS8YHYJZhLMk) is a short example in plunkr.  Click on 'refresh' button once (or more) to see the extra 'd_sampleObject' object instance that is leaked (in Chrome Profile Inspection). Note, the 'd_sampleObject' name is only used when passed to ng-repeat. I have included screenshots of the extra object instance ('d_sampleObject') that is being leaked further below. Why is there a leak and how can it be avoided?

(Note, I have found if I don't iterate over my object collection (JS array) thru an object but rather thru a primitive index ('integer'), there is no leak. The leak seems to only happen when I use an object reference as a result of ng-repeat iterations)

### **SIMPLE HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="memoryleak">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Memory Leak Test</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="dataservice.js"></script>    
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


    <div ng-repeat="d_sampleObject in mySampleObjects">
        {{d_sampleObject.description}}
    </div>

    <br>

    <button ng-click="redo()">Number of refreshes: {{numRedos}}!</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

### **SIMPLE APP.JS**

```
(function(ml) {
    var app = angular.module('memoryleak',['servicemodule']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataservice', function($scope, dataservice) {

        $scope.redo = function () {

            $scope.numRedos++;

            $scope.mySampleObjects = dataservice.myObjectCollection;

            dataservice.redo();
        }

        $scope.redo();

    }]);

}(window.MEMLEAK = window.MEMLEAK || {}));
```

### **SIMPLE dataservice.js**

```
(function(ml) {

    'use strict';

    var serviceModule = angular.module('servicemodule',[]);

    serviceModule.factory('dataservice', ['$rootScope', '$http',
                                        function ($rootScope, $http) {

        this.myObjectCollection = [];

        this.redo = function () {

                this.numRedos++;

            // that.myObjectCollection = [];
            this.myObjectCollection.length = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
                var sampleObject = new ml.MySampleObject(i);

                that.myObjectCollection.push(sampleObject);
            }   


            sampleObject=null;        

        }

        ml.MySampleObject = function (id) {

            this.id = id;
            this.description = 'this is object #:' + ' '+id;
        }  

        return this;   //return the entire service to make methods accessible to dependents

    }]);

}(window.MEMLEAK = window.MEMLEAK || {}));
```

SCREENSHOT 1:  (FIRST PAGE LOAD--there are 10 'mySampleObjects' created)
[image: SCREENSHOT 1: (FIRST PAGE LOAD--there are 10 'mySampleObjects' created)]
 SCREENSHOT 2:  (CLICKED ON REFRESH--there is an 11th mySampleObject created/leaked with a reference to the instance name of 'd_sampleObject' passed to ng-repeat.)
[image: (CLICKED ON REFRESH--there is an 11th mySampleObject created/leaked with a reference to the instance name of 'd_sampleObject' passed to ng-repeat.)]

Answer (score 5):

There is [acknowledgement](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11169) by the AngularJS folks that this is indeed a bug in the framework.  A fix and pull request has been [posted](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11169).

I have also asked what the timeframe is for a formal fix.

Comment: Looks like it's been implemented in [1.4.0-beta.6](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fb7db4a07bd1b0b67824d3808fe315419b272689)