# Is an image still present in the DOM even though it is not displayed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I find that my Ionic/Angular app constantly crashes after ~5 minutes of usage on my iPhone 6. It doesn’t crash when I use it on my computer’s browser.

I’ve been trying to troubleshoot the issue but have not been able to do so successfully. In my app, I have 48 images. In 1 round, I show 4 images. When the round starts, the user sees all 4 images. And the user can then pick which image he wants to guess on. In my javascript, this is represented as $scope.locations variable which is an array containing 4 objects. One of the attributes of each object is the link to the image to display. In my template, I loop through the 4 images using ng-repeat.

After the user is done with 1 image, he/she goes back to the home page and that object is removed from $scope.locations. And then the template runs through ng-repeat once again.

My hypothesis is that even though the image is not visually on the screen, it is still in the DOM and there are still some listeners present for the object that has been removed. Is this a valid concern? If so, how do I resolve this?

I'm thinking that this is why the app is crashing so often.

Comment: Have you looked at the dom to conform your hypothesis?

Comment: When I used collection-repeat, I'd still see those images in the DOM and they would have CSS styling to hide them. But when I use ng-repeat, I don't see them in the DOM. However, I don't know if there are still listeners for them?

Comment: Do you know where the app is breaking?  Have you tried running some debugging tools to find potential leaks?

Comment: This might be helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683992/angularjs-memory-leak-with-ng-repeat-using-custom-objects-w-simple-plunkr

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The image is present and can be resized even if it fails to display. I know due to personal experience with the side effects of blocking ads and turning on a bunch of accessibility settings.

Getting attributes from the image tends to not work for the obvious reason; but URL is there.