# angular 1.5.x ngRepeat memory leak

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

I created a list module that can display multiple pages of items. I am using a nested ng-repeat to iterate through pages and the items on each page. However, I've noticed DOM Nodes keep increasing in Chrome Timeline tool like this when I keep refreshing the list and load new pages and items, memory usage is also increasing(I made sure I clicked on garbage collection button during recording, so there must be something leaking):
[image: Nodes Graph from Chrome Timeline]

I am using angular 1.5.5 and requireJS, I've heard ng-repeat used to have a memory leak but that already got fixed in 1.4.x. The code is simple and I didn't register any DOM handlers in the code, I have been poking around on this for a week and still couldn't figure out the reason, I am very desperate now and help is super appreciated.

My code file structure is like this:

```
list-container
     |___module.js
     |
     |___controllers
     |       |____list-container.js
     |
     |___directives
     |       |____list-container.js
     |
     |___views
           |____directive-list-container.html
```

Below is the code:

module.js

```
define([
  'angular',
], function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  return angular.module('ui.listContainer', []);
});
```

list-container.js(directive)

```
define([
  'angular',
  '../module',
  '../controllers/list-container'
], function (angular, module) {
  'use strict';


  return angular
    .module('ui.listContainer')
    .directive('listContainer', function () {
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '/modules/list-container/views/directive-list-container.html',
      bindToController: {},
      scope: {},
      controllerAs: 'listVm',
      controller: 'listContainerController'
    };
  });
});
```

list-container.js(controller)

```
define([
   'angular',
   '../module'
 ], function (angular, module) {
   'use strict';
   angular.module('ui.listContainer').controller('listContainerController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

     var listVm = this;

     $scope.refreshPage = function () {
       if (listVm.list) {
         listVm.list = null; //Clear the data
       }
       listVm.list = {};
       listVm.list.pages = feedData(); //Load mock data
     };


     function feedData() {
       var pages = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         pages.push(new PageMock());
       }
       return pages;
     }

     function PageMock() {
       this.items = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
         this.items.push(new ItemMock());
       }
     }

     function ItemMock() {
       this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000);
     }

   }]);
 });
```

directive-list-container.html(view)

```
<div class="list-container row">
    <div id="list-container-pages">
        <div class="list-container-pages row">
            <div ng-click="refreshPage()">Refresh Page</div>
            <div class="list-container-page row" ng-repeat="page in listVm.list.pages track by $index">
                <div class="row" ng-repeat="listItem in page.items track by listItem.id">
                    <span class="col-md-12">{{listItem.id}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a plunker to mimic the code I have above, however it's not leaking at all in the plunker example, which is super weird.
[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rZ0V3PQMGUuRuqMH4cp6?p=info)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in angular, see the other post.
[AngularJS: Memory Leak with ng-repeat using custom objects (w/simple PLUNKR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683992/angularjs-memory-leak-with-ng-repeat-using-custom-objects-w-simple-plunkr)

Comment: That post refers to angular 1.4.something, and is supposedly fixed. I can't seem to find the commit in the actual repo, though, and I see the same behaviour in some angular 1.5.8-code I'm maintaining.

Comment: I am using angular 1.5 and this behaviour of gradual memory increase is still present. I ended up putting a timer with periodic refresh of the page as a workaround.

Comment: Using angularjs 1.6.4 and this is still happening as a work around add "track by $index" where ever you have an ng-repeat (does not work with filters) and also refresh the page every hour or so helps too.